# Regenerate sitemaps for every registered user?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a .Net website where the main functionality is viewing user profiles.
Suppose if my URL to view a profile is `www.mywebsite.com/viewprofile?id=20`, to see a user with an id of 20. My question is do I need to add all the URLs for every registered users to the sitemap?

For example: `www.mywebsite.com/viewprofile?id=20`, `www.mywebsite.com/viewprofile?id=21` etc

Or just adding a URL of `www.mywebsite.com/viewprofile` is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those pages to be crawled and indexed then you *should* put them in your sitemap. The point of sitemaps is to tell the search engines about the pages on your website so if new members sign up their profile page should be added to the sitemap.

Of course they don't *have* to be in the sitemap if they can be found through links within your website (or from external sites, too). But not including them would be sort of defeating the purpose of having a sitemap.

Comment: thank you ! , but does that mean that if i have 10,000 users i need to have 10000 urls ? i am assuming there is no limit to the size ?

Comment: Correct. There is a limit of sorts to individual sitemaps but you can submit multiple sitemaps. See sitemaps.org for how to do that.